# PHP : название файла в качестве переменной

Tags: php

Можно как то сделать чтоб это работало? чтоб цикл по очереди выводил содержимое файлов которые имеют имена `1.html`, `2.html`, `3.html`, и т.д

```
<?php 
while($fl!=5)
{
  $fl=1;
  $file = file_get_contents('$fl.html', true);
  echo '<b>'.$file.'</b><br>';
  echo  date(" d F y H:i:s.", filectime('$fl.html'));
  $fl++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Очередной вопрос про форматирование строк в РНР. Я даже [страницу мануала](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php) не успел закрыть. В одинарных кавычках переменные не интерполируются. Для этого надо использовать двойные.